# jQuery.width() is returning percentage width instead of pixel width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please have a look at the following 2 jsFiddle examples:

**Example number 1**

The first one is pure html and a single call to the Jquery width function which then return the width as expected in pixels.
[Demo with pure HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/qvt2ad1t/4/)

**HTML**:

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-a" data-pinterest-extension-installed="cr1.38.2" style="background-color: rgb(255, 182, 50);">
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="mailiPage" style="">
        <div id="mainDiv" data-role="content" class="ui-content" data-theme="b" style="text-align:center;background-color:#ffb632;background-image:none;height:100%">
            <div class="ui-grid-b">
                <div id="left" class="ui-block-a" style="width:5%;"></div>
                <div id="center" class="ui-block-b" style="width:90%;"></div>
                <div id="right" class="ui-block-c" style="width:5%;"></div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
alert('this width of the center div is in pixels: ' + $('#center').width() + '\n');
```

**Example number 2**

The second example include the javascript that is used to write the html dynamically and than a call to the width function which in this case return the percentage value and not the pixel width.
[Demo with only Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/orihadar/exuwhjL5/5/)

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var strPage = ""
var leftSideColumnsWidth = 5;
var rightSideColumnsWidth = 5;
var centerColumnsWidth = 90;
$("body").empty();
strPage = strPage + "<div data-role='page' data-theme='b' id='mailiPage' style=''>"
strPage = strPage +     "<div id='mainDiv' data-role='content' class='ui-content' data-theme='b' style='text-align:center;background-color:#ffb632;background-image:none;height:100%'>" //padding-top: 56px;'>"
strPage = strPage +         "<div class='ui-grid-b'>" 
strPage = strPage +             "<div id='left' class='ui-block-a' style='width:" + leftSideColumnsWidth + "%;'>"
strPage = strPage +             "</div>"
strPage = strPage +             "<div id='center' class='ui-block-b' style='width:" + centerColumnsWidth + "%;'>"
strPage = strPage +             "</div>"
strPage = strPage +             "<div id='right' class='ui-block-c' style='width:" + rightSideColumnsWidth + "%;'>"
strPage = strPage +             "</div>"
strPage = strPage +         "</div>"
strPage = strPage +     "</div>"
strPage = strPage + "</div>" 

$("body").append(strPage);

alert('this width of the center div is not in pixels but in percentage: ' +$('#center').width()+'\n');
```

Any idea why is it deffer?

**UPDATE:**

In the dynamic version if you mark out the first div which define the JQM page and include "data-role='page'", the width function will return the value in pixels!!
Now the question remains WHY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery Mobile pages i.e. div elements with `[data-role=page]` are initially hidden. And for hidden elements:

> The value reported by [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is not guaranteed to be accurate
>   when the element or its parent is hidden. To get an accurate value,
>   ensure the element is visible before using `.width()`. jQuery will
>   attempt to temporarily show and then re-hide an element in order to
>   measure its dimensions, but this is unreliable and (even when
>   accurate) can significantly impact page performance. This
>   show-and-rehide measurement feature may be removed in a future version
>   of jQuery.

Having said that, you might want to [look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/exuwhjL5/7/), which hooks pageshow events to determine if the page (and therefore the element) is visible.

Comment: Yes, the explanation is that the `.width()` call runs before the corresponding element is rendered, but what does jquery mobile have to do with anything?

Comment: @blgt The "page" that is created by JavaScript is hidden because of jQuery mobile CSS.